# maven support in bluemix vs heroku java buildpack

Tags: java, maven, heroku, ibm-cloud, buildpack

Bluemix seems to support heroku buildpacks, and the java buildpack for heroku has the ability to build a project from a maven pom.xml file.

However, in bluemix, the devops service needs to be used to build using maven and then deploy to the cloud.

Has anyone used the heroku java buildpack in bluemix to deploy a project with just a pm, instead of a pre-build war ?

Are there any dis-advantages to using the heroku java buildpack in bluemix ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this [Java sample app for Heroku](https://github.com/heroku/java-getting-started) and just successfully pushed it to Bluemix using the [Heroku Java buildpack](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-java).

So it works, at least for simple cases, but there are disadvantages:

- can't have a deployment pipeline where the same build artifact is deployed to multiple places (like test, staging, production, etc.)
- not designed to leverage any specific features of Bluemix or Cloud Foundry
- the only documentation is for Heroku

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to run Maven with the Cloud Foundry plug-in locally so you can deploy and manage your apps to Bluemix with Maven goals.
There's an article about it here: https://www.ibm.com/blogs/bluemix/2015/01/using-cloud-foundry-maven-plugin-deploy-apps-bluemix/

Comment: Thanks. I did consider this as well, but wanted a better understanding of the differences between the heroku/bluemix buildpacks and if they are indeed compatible.